# A projectile is launched with a velocity of 30 m/s at 40° to the ground. To two decimal places, what is its horizontal velocity in m/s?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

A projectile is launched with a velocity of $30 \, m/s$ at $40^\circ$ to the ground.  To two decimal places, what is its horizontal velocity in $m/s$?

A ball is thrown downward from the top of a $20\, m$ tall building with an initial velocity of $15 \,m/s$.  What equation could be used to model its height, $h(t)$?

What is the solution for theses two questions? What steps do you use to solve them? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 4 upvotes? Why?

Answer (score 1):

1. Typically with physics questions with projectiles the angle is given with respect to the horizontal, so you have 
   $$
   v_x = v \cos(\theta)
   $$
   $$
   v_y = v \sin(\theta)
   $$
   In this case, you have
   $$
   v_x = 30 \cos(40^\circ)
   $$
2. With constant acceleration and an initial velocity,
   $$
   \Delta y = v_i t + \frac{1}{2}g t ^2
   $$

Comment: how did you get that solution for 2?

Comment: Well, usually it is simply an equation you are given in physics classes.  It is possible to derive it using calculus, by taking the double integral of a constant acceleration.